# How does JIRA show the hierarchical view of the Epics, Stories and Tasks in Dashboard?

Tags: jira, user-stories, epic

To manage the scrum development process of a big community website, we decided to move to JIRA/Greenhopper/Bonfire.
I have created elaborate Epic, Stories and Tasks, all well linked to each other.

I would like to develop the "Product Story" in more detail all the time by adding new Epics, new Stories to (new or existing) Epics, etc.

To be able to do this properly, I want to have a hierarchical overview of all issues: Epics, Stories, Tasks, etc.

Question: How do we set this up in JIRA?

Why?
=> My approach is from the point of view of project management: getting everybody aligned around the same vision. However, I think it is part for everyone in the team -especially for the ones who are actually building the product- to have a quick view of how their current or planned work fits into the big picture.

Comment: Is Structure a good solution?

Comment: I work for the guys who make Structure so I'll avoid giving a biased subjective answer :) But I can say objectively that this is a very typical use case among our customers. If you contact support we'll be happy to demo/advise on this and many other applications of Structure (you have to be self-hosted though!).

Answer (score 2):

Stories have sub-tasks, which will be shown hierarchically in the Sprint, but all sub-tasks have to be completed in the sprint of the user story. I also think when you create a story you can specify an epic, which will create a hard-link ( the same as story -> sub-task). Is there a reason you want to use a Jira task? To me it looks that in a SCRUM environment you only need  Epics, stories and sub-tasks. Maybe some spikes and support tickets from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a tool like Rally, I can appreciate you wanting to see the big picture.  We transitioned from Rally to Greenhopper over a year ago mainly because of costs.  Lets just say you get what your pay for.  I haven't found the feature you're looking for in Greenhopper, it only has a single threaded view for things like Epics to Stories (on the planning page) or Stories to tasks on the (on the work page)